# Long exact sequence of reduced homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

Here are two fragments out of Hatcher's book (see [http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) for the full book).

[image]

Questions: (1) Does this mean we get a long exact sequence which has the form
$$\dots \to\tilde{H}_n(A) \to \tilde{H}_n(X) \to H_n(X,A) \to \tilde{H}_{n-1}(A) \to \tilde{H}_{n-1} \to \dots$$

Or do I need to modify the $H_n(X,A)$ by $\tilde{H}_n(X,A)$ or something like that?

(2) Can someone explain the second paragraph in the picture in some detail? I was not able to understand what Hatcher was trying to explain.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The second paragraph explains what happens for reduced homology. In particular, it answers your first question.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese So is the answer to the first question yes?

Comment: The question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3297906 is not the same as the present one, but its answer contains all necessary details. Question (1): Yes.